# Derivatives Across Summations

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, tensors, matrix-calculus, index-notation

So, I took one intro course in Tensor calculus and this problem reminds of that, except I can't quite recall how derivatives work with respect to components, or what those derivatives produce. Consider the following example:

[image]

The transition from (7) to (8) is where I'm lost. We have

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_{jk}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial X_{jk}} \sum_i \sum_j \sum_k A_{ij}X_{jk}B_{ki}
$$

Now, the ultimate goal here is to find $\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}$, so why did we choose to differentiate on the indices $(j,k)$. Clearly that's a convenient choice, but why is it acceptable to choose, what is the intuition or motivation for that choice (this is my main question)? Given that it is the correct choice, I believe the derivative and subsequent work goes somewhat like:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial X_{jk}} \sum_i \sum_j \sum_k A_{ij}X_{jk}B_{ki} &= 
\sum_i \sum_j \sum_k A_{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial X_{jk}}\left(X_{jk}\right)B_{ki} \\
&= \sum_i \sum_j \sum_k A_{ij}1_{jk}B_{ki} \\ 
&= \sum_i \sum_j A_{ij} \sum_k 1_{jk}B_{ki} \tag{$\star$} \\
&= \sum_i \sum_j A_{ij}B{ji}
\end{align}

But my steps in/around $(\star)$ are not legitimate. I sense that there should be some kronecker delta action around there. In tensor notation I get:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial X_{jk}} A_{ij}X_{jk}B_{ki} &= 
 A_{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial X_{jk}}\left(X_{jk}\right)B_{ki} \\
&=  A_{ij}B_{ki} \\
&= \left[BA\right]_{kj} \\
&= \left[BA\right]^T_{jk} \\
&= \left[A^TB^T\right]_{jk} \\
\end{align}

which are the components of $A^TB^T$. So that seems to work fine (am I correct?). If so, how do I reconcile the notations in order to perform the same calculation in index notation?

Answer (score 1):

I can see the confusion in the notation, so let's change things up a little bit to try and make it clearer.

First let's note what our coordinates are:  For convenience, all indices range from from $1$ to $n$.  We have coordinates of the form $(X_{ij})=(X_{ij}, 1\leq i,j\leq n)$.  Then for fixed matrices $A$ and $B$, we have that $X_{ij}(A)=A_{ij}$ and $X_{ij}(B)=B_{ij}$.  Then our function $f(X)$, in coordinates is written as
$$f((X_{ij}))=\sum_i\sum_j\sum_kA_{ij}X_{jk}B_{ki}.$$
Now let's differentiate with respect to a fixed coordinate $X_{ab}$.  Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_{ab}}&=\frac{\partial}{\partial X_{ab}}\sum_i\sum_j\sum_kA_{ij}X_{jk}B_{ki}\\
&=\sum_i\sum_j\sum_kA_{ij}B_{ki}\frac{\partial X_{jk}}{\partial X_{ab}}\\
&=\sum_i\sum_j\sum_kA_{ij}B_{ki}\delta_{aj}\delta_{bk}\\
&=\sum_iA_{ia}B_{bi}\\
&=\sum_iB_{bi}A_{ia}\\
&=X_{ba}(BA)\\
&=X_{ab}((BA)^T)\\
&=X_{ab}(A^TB^T).
\end{align*}

Now,
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_{ab}}=X_{ab}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}\right)$$
by definition, and hence
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}=A^TB^T.$$

Answer (score 1):

Since you took a course covering tensors, you are undoubtedly familiar with the index summation convention. If we let $\partial_{ij}$ denote the derivative wrt $X_{ij}$, then the derivation quite succinct
$$\eqalign{
f &= A_{ij}X_{jk}B_{ki} \cr
\partial_{mp}f
  &= A_{ij}\,(\partial_{mp}X_{jk})\,B_{ki} \cr
  &= A_{ij}\,(\delta_{mj}\delta_{pk})\,B_{ki} \cr
  &= A_{im}B_{pi} \cr
  &= A^T_{mi}B^T_{ip} \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} &= A^TB^T \cr\cr
}$$

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, why is this author taking the derivative with respect to the *same* indices, in regards to $X$. Are they simply wrong?

Comment: They were abusing notation, the $X_{jk}$ on the LHS is not the same $X_{jk}$ on the RHS, that's what I was trying to clarify in my answer by using the the Kronecker delta.  Moreover, the above answer is not Einstein summation convention, as you should only implicitly sum over an index that is both raised and lowered in the expression, i.e., $\omega_iX^i=\sum_i\omega_iX^i$.  Otherwise you're implying the Euclidean metric on your space.